# JavaScript function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm using the following JavaScript code:

```
var emp= new Object();
emp["name"]="pooja";
emp["salary"]=725;

emp["paycheck"]=function()
 {
  var monthly=this["salary"]/12;
  alert(this["name"]+":"+monthly);
 };

emp["paycheck"]();       --work properly 
document.write("<br/>");
var f=emp["paycheck"];    --dosen't work
f();
```

f() have to get reference on emp["paycheck"] function and display a suitable answer.
but insted i get NaN.

As i understood f() dosen't see the property of emp object("name" and "salary").
My question is why f() dosen't see the properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You refer to salary as `this["salary"]`. If you store the function and call it later, the `this` value is lost. It is only bound to the object if you *directly* call it, as in `emp.paycheck()`. You could pass the `this` value explicitly, though:

```
f.call(emp);
```

But you might rather want to refer to salary in the function as `emp["salary"]`, since that will always work.

Note that instead of `foo["bar"]` you can use `foo.bar`, and that the `new Object()` part can just be:

```
var emp = {
  name: "pooja",

  salary: 725,

  paycheck: function() {
    ...
  }
};
```

Comment: This method is the far more commonly accepted way to build an object.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why is you are calling the function without a `this` parameter.  You need to use `apply` to pass it an explicit `this` on which it can call the `name` and `salary` properties.

```
f.apply(emp);
```

Answer (score 1):

you reference on a function, not on all object.

```
f = emp;   
f.paycheck();
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't copy those properties to `f`. There are, unfortunately, no native ways to do this in JavaScript. See [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript) or [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object), look at jQuery's `extend()`, or google "javascript deep copy object" or  "javascript clone object".

Answer (score 1):

Others have explained what's going on and how you don't pass `this`.

However, if you want to do something like this (a custom from Python perhaps?), you can make a helper function:

```
function makeDelegate(obj, fun) {
    return function() {
        fun.apply(obj, arguments);
    };
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var f = makeDelegate(emp, emp["paycheck"]);
f();
```